# Derangements: n men, n umbrellas and n coats

Tags: combinatorics

A number of men enter a disreputable establishment and each one leaves a coat and
an umbrella at the door. When a message is received saying that the establishment is about
to be raided by the police, the men leave hurriedly, and no man gets both the right coat and
the umbrella. If there are n men, show that the number of ways in which this can happen is

$n!(n!-\frac{(n-1)!}{1!} + \frac{(n-2)!}{2!} - ... + (-1)^n\frac{1}{n!})$

So that was the question which sparked my interest, but I would like to ask about a different situation in which every man gets a wrong hat AND a wrong coat.

One can compute in how many ways they can get their coats wrong ($D_n$ - derangements of n). For each of these derangements there are another $D_n$ ways in which they can get their umbrellas wrong - so that the number of ways both are wrong is $D_n^2$.

Is there a mistake in this logic? Thank you.

Comment: I think the question as you have stated it suggests that no-one goes home with both correct, but one correct item is possible.

Comment: This is why i wrote that assumption. But if i wanted to know in how many ways each one can go home with the wrong hat AND the wrong coat (both wrong), would $D_n^2$ be the answer? Thank you.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing the question  to reflect your comment, please check that it asks what you want to know. HINT - hats and coats are independent,

Comment: Yes, it asks what i intend to find out. Anyway, computing this would make it easier to solve the original problem, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the original problem can be done as "wrong hat + any coat" + "wrong coat + any hat" - "wrong coat + wrong hat" (which has been double-counted: can you see the derangement idea at work again?)

Also I think you are right in your calculation of both wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the proof for the original problem as well. 
Let $T$ be the set of all the ways in which they could take their items ( $|T|=n!n!$ ).

Now let $A_i$ be the set of all the ways in which person $i$ takes both his umbrella and his coat.

We need to compute $|T \setminus (\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^nA_i)|. $

All that is left is to remark that $|\bigcap \limits_{i \in I}A_i| = {n \choose k}(n-k)!^2$, where $k=|I|$.